# Nagios Monitoring Text on a Website contents

Tags: nagios

I need a plugin that allows me to nagios looking for a well-defined text in the content of my web page. if the text is found I would ok sion error
who can help me please

Answer (score 4):

The standard plugin `check_http` can do this:

```
check_http -H [hostname] -I [ip address] -u [url] -R [text to match]
```

The check will fail for the usual reasons, but also if the text (or regular expression) is not found in the returned page.

If you want to fail if the text *is* found, add the option `--invert-regex`.

Comment: I have 
HTTP CRITICAL: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request - pattern not found - 1270 bytes in 0,069 second response time |time=0,068840s;;;0,000000 size=1270B;;;0

Comment: Strange that you got a 400.  What was the full command line you used?

Comment: check_http -H chourouk1 -I @IP -u www.alchourouk.com -R "Site web réalisé par"

Comment: The argument for `-u` should be the path part of the URL.  Try `-u /`.  You might also have to do `-H www.alchourouk.com` if your host has more than one virtual host.

Comment: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -H www.alchourouk.com -u /  -R "Site web réalisé"
HTTP CRITICAL: HTTP/1.1 302 Found - pattern not found - 443 bytes in 0,402 second response time |time=0,402222s;;;0,000000 size=443B;;;0

Comment: Ah, you must be doing a redirect (you're getting a `302`).  You need to specify the precise path of the page as the argument to `-u`.  Do a `curl -I http://www.alchourouk.com/`, and look for the `Location: ` header.  This is the value you need to specify.

Comment: when I execute  the command curl -I http://www.alchourouk.com/ I get nothing as a result

Comment: That's strange, because I do.  I get a string in Arabic.

Comment: ok do you have any idea please

Comment: I've no idea if this will paste correctly, but try `-u الصفحة-الرئيسية_46_4`.  If that doesn't work then you're on your own; I'm afraid I have my own problems :)

Comment: Unfortunately I could not paste :'(

Answer (score 0):

Flup's answer seems great for a simple page.

If you want to do something similar but need to navigate through a set of login pages, we make use of http://webinject.org/ which allows a test to fill in forms etc.